# How to build the arguments list for Popen when one of the arguments has the format "-c name=value"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to run a git clone from Python but I need to disable the credentials popup you get on Windows, but only for this clone.

This is what I tried:

```
p = Popen(
    [
        "C:\\git.exe",
        "-c",
        "credential.helper=\"\"",
        "clone",
        "https://abc:abc@url.git",
        "C:\\path"
    ],
    stderr=PIPE,
    stdout=PIPE,
)

p.wait()
c = p.communicate()
print(c[0].decode("utf-8"))
print(c[1].decode("utf-8"))
```

But running this code still shows the credentials popup. Once I manually close the window I get the following output:

> Cloning into 'C:\path'... 
>   git: 'credential-' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
>
> The most similar command is credential

Running the command directly on the terminal works without issue and joining the arguments string into a single string and using that as the parameter to Popen also works, which tells me issue is probably related to how Popen parses arguments with an equal sign in them..?

How can I build this arguments list?

Comment: One important thing to understand is that quotes that aren't escaped themselves are instructions to the shell about how to interpret the characters contained therein; they **aren't** passed to the program that shell runs. That is to say, in a POSIX-compliant shell, `foo --bar="baz"` is **exactly identical** to `foo --bar=baz`, and `foo --bar="baz qux"` is exactly identical to `foo --bar=baz' 'qux`, as in, `foo` has no way of knowing which of those options was used, as they result in identical C strings being passed to the `execv`-family syscall.

Comment: ...now, on Windows, that's a little different, because on Windows the interface isn't `execve`-style at all; instead of an array, a string is passed between processes and the receiving process's libc is responsible for parsing it. *However*, with the default `shell=False`, Popen is pretending you're on a UNIX-y operating system, and unless you really know what you're doing and why, it pays to act accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell is likely removing the quotes in `credential.helper=""`; try this instead:

```
p = Popen(
    [
        "C:\\git.exe",
        "-c",
        "credential.helper=",  # note no extra quotes here
        "clone",
        "https://abc:abc@url.git",
        "C:\\path"
    ],
    stderr=PIPE,
    stdout=PIPE,
)
```

That way you set `credential.helper` to nothing, rather than to the empty string, which presumably git treats differently (I assume if you have `credential.helper=foo`, git tries to run `git credential-foo`, so with the empty string specified, it tries to run `git credential-`, which won't work).